# I am a US citizen wanting to Drive an India registered car from India to UK - Who gives me the Carnet?

Tags: india, us-citizens, automobiles, carnet-de-passage

I am a US citizen and live in India and drive Indian registered cars. I want to drive these cars from India to the UK next year. Who gives me the Carnet? I hear Carnets are not given to foreign citizens in India.

Comment: As an aside, I think a US citizen is going to have more trouble that just getting a Carnet de Passage on that route.

Comment: I believe you have to have permanent residence status to get a Carnet in India.

Comment: I do have an OCI which is an Overseas Citizen of India passport. Will this qualify me to get a Carnet in India?

Comment: @AnilSrivatsa You should edit your question to include this information, not everyone will read the comments